# Wifi connected and shows internet access but cant use internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, ethernet

Basically I have my Ethernet cable that comes from my neighbor and then I plug it into my router and that router gives Wi-Fi and device is connected to Wi-Fi and it shows internet access too but not able to launch any websites, but direct connecting of that Ethernet cable to laptop transmits the internet.

Does anyone see what the issue is? Can a router not work with someone else's Ethernet cable that possibly has a different router with them.

Comment: I assume you mean router instead of modem? What port on the router are you plugging into? WAN or LAN?

Comment: @SamForbis From the LAN of the other router to the WAN of my router

Comment: Only thing I can think of immediately is that the two routers use the same subnet (i.e. 192.168.0.0/24). This would cause the internet on the downstream router to not work. See what subnet your neighbor's router uses, then use your router's config page to make sure you aren't on conflicting subnets.

Comment: @SamForbis So I should change the subnet or should I be changing the IP address of the router, I think the IP address of both router is different too.

Comment: Well, it depends, was I correct in assuming that the routers are configured to use the same network? If not, then you don't need to do anything and that's not your issue. If they are the same, then you will need to change your router's DHCP range to another subnet and then change your router's IP address to match that new subnet.

Comment: What's the configuration of the networkcard of the PC if you plug in the cable directly? What's the configuration of your router? It's impossible to give you specific advice without more information.

Comment: @samforbis Oh okays I'll take a look into that.

Comment: @albin More info, well I'm not sure what's going on, anyway I'll try some fixes around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what your neighbour actually "provides through the cable" you have two options:

- If you don't need routing functionality you can disable it (including DHCP) in your router an just use it as an access point (often called something like bridge mode). This could also work if you just plug it into a LAN port of your router.
- Enable routing/NAT on your router and configure your router "correctly". Unfortunately more info is needed to give you advice on the issue.

Comment: Okays man, I got an idea of things I guess. Thanks for the help.